# pgrouting - Choosing an algorithm with a predominance for a specific type of road

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, algorithm, osm2pgrouting, shortest-path

I would like to use one of pgrouting's algorithm to find the (shortest) path between 2 points with predominance for a specific type of road.

To build the data I used the osm2pgrouting.

Is there an algorithm where I could define my preferences for the road type (in table ways class_id column class_id which represents road type or in table osm_way_types)?  If not how should I tweak my database? Knowing that I used the osm2pgrouting --> there is table public.osm_way_classes there is max_speed but it seems poor choice for tweaking it. I would like to leave it alone. I didn't really find anything useful in other tables. Any ideas?

@edit (second question deleted) I saw that in dijkstra algorithm there is cost in inside query. Maybe add column priority to way_classes (or way_types). And then join the table ways with table way_classes and then with table way_types. So in query there won't be ST_Length / length in cost but length * priority. What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to [gis.se]. Please visit the [tour] to learn about our focused Q/A standards. Please limit your post to one question per question. You can [edit] your question to make it more specific.

Comment: It's not a bad question. Remove b and I will vote to reopen and attempt an answer

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça done :-)

Comment: Voted to reopen. Think it needs five of us to do so. +2 so far

Answer (score 1):

All pgRouting shortest path functions can do what you want to do. "Shortest" in pgRouting means minimum `cost`, which every pgRouting function allows you to define.

I recommend you the pgRouting workshop, which explains in chapter [Advanced Routing Queries](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/chapters/advanced.html), how to change the `cost` attribute.